# Android DetailsSupportFragment focus action programmatically

Tags: android, leanback

Im using  android leanback library and in DetailFragment I want to do the next - when return on actionadapter focused first action, how can I focused action programmatically?

I know what I must doing it in setOnItemViewSelectedListener

```
setOnItemViewSelectedListener((itemViewHolder, item, rowViewHolder, row) -> {
        if (item instanceof Action){
            Action action = (Action) item;
            if (action.getId() != getFirstActionID()); {
                //how requestfocus on first action?
            }
        }
    });

private long getFirstActionID(){
    if (mDetailsOverviewRow.getActionsAdapter().size() > 0){
        return ((Action)mDetailsOverviewRow.getActionsAdapter().get(0)).getId();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: please try to make your question more understandable. currently it's unclear what you asking

Comment: Im asking how I can focused(request focus) on action. (DetailsSupportFragment - Leanback)